# Windows Server 2016 failed to boot on ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi, windows-server-2016, bsod

I have 2 similar DELL Poweredge servers (ESXi 6.0 2809209).
My servers contain some Windows Server 2008/2012.

I can add an Windows Server 2016 Standard Desktop Experience normally on my first ESXi (T430 with 2xSandyBridge Xeon E5-2620).

But this doesn't work on my second ESXi (T440 with 2xSkylake Xeon Silver 4110) :

- I can install Windows Server 2016 on a new VM (hardward version 11)
- "windows failed to start 0xc0000001" after the **very first reboot** (before install vmtools or open the session)
- BSOD "kmode exception not handled" stop code

Tested with old and updated ISO.
Tested with Windows Server 2019 too.

If i move this VM to the first ESXi, the VM boot successfully.

I don't understand the different behavior between similar situation. I don't kown how to diagnose that. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Additionnal information
No difference BIOS/EFI mode
No difference with/without license key
No difference Core/Desktop experience
No difference low memory, low CPU/high memory, high CPU